# Visual Studio Express 2015 for windows 10 does't have visual basic form template

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-10, visual-studio-express

I can't find that, is there a problem? Please I can't find it not even in the C# or C++ or javascript, please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows targets the Universal Windows Platform, not WinForms. For WinForms you'll need Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop or Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

If you meet it's licensing requirements I'd recommend the Community Edition.

See: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx